# Is it possible to use docker as dev enviornment for golang app engine standard enviornment?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

My understanding is that docker needs App Engine Flexible Environment.

But I want to use Docker to create dev and local testing environment only, so that it will be easier and faster to replicate the environment on dev machines. I still want to deploy the [GoLang](https://www.golang.org) app to App Engine Standard Environment. I am wondering if there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build [custom runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) using Docker, you will only need App Engine Flexible if you want to deploy them. In your case, as you want to deploy to App Engine Standard, I would recommend using the [Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server) to simulate  correctly the environment.

Comment: Thanks, is there any docker image that contains development server you would recommend?

Comment: There's the official Cloud SDK docker image which comes with all components installed, which may include the devserver. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker) for more details and try it. As I've never used it I'm not sure you'll be able to achieve what you want with this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Containers with App Engine Standard. You can use containers with App Engine Flexible.

Comment: I don't want to use container with App Engine. I just want to use container for development so we don't have to waste time to setup the development environment over and over again for new dev.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood your question.